# Создание Админ программы для софта

Tags: c#

Появилась идея написание некого софта, который возможно будет дистрибьютироваться, и по задумке к нему нужно создать Админ прогу которая будет инжектить данные в основной .exe файл. Данные в виде настроек GUI, а так же сетевые адреса инпута/аутпута данных.

Что почитать на данную тематику или как прогуглить данный вопрос? Если такое возможно желательно примеры на C#.

Comment: А почему странный инжект в файл, а не привычные всем отдельно лежащие settings?

Comment: Хочется сделать админ программу тоже гуи + интерактивную настройку интерфейса для админа. Что-то по типа редактора файлов ресурсов. Вроде был Restorator. И сурсы никому не будут доступны.

Comment: Плюс один к мнению, что более простой и удобный способ - это хранить данные в настройках. Вы пока не озвучили никакой причины, почему нужно делать дольше, сложнее и с большим числом багов. Возможно, у вас будет только два аргумента ("хочу вот так" или "это в учебных целях"), но нужно понимать, что подобными тропами редко ходят и поэтому особо ничего не нагуглится - придётся быть первопроходцем, собирая кучу шишек. Сеттингсы - это просто, для инжекта вам придётся очень глубоко разбираться в устройстве программ, компилятора, языка. Может нужнее не "шашечки", а "ехать"?

Comment: "И сурсы никому не будут доступны". Это же C#, он очень просто декомпилируется. Для настроек используйте стандартные вещи, типа settings, ini-файлов, реестра. Хотите защитить исходники - повесьте на ваш софт лицензию, которая запретит использовать код вашего ПО или вынесите важную логику на сервер.

Comment: А что Вы будете делать, когда по каким-либо причинам Ваш сервер переедет на другой домен? В принципе, как будете обновлять Ваше приложение, когда оно будет уже на пользовательских машинах?